# i used python on raspberry to read ph water from arduino

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, arduino, raspberry-pi

I create a project to read pH water, but my module sensor doesn't fix with raspberry pi 3 so I using Arduino to read pH, then send to raspberry and upload the data to firebase.

but, I have some problem, when raspberry read data from Arduino, the looping doesn't work. the error message is serial.util.serialexception

here's source code on Raspberry

```
import os
import serial
import time
from firebase import firebase

arduino = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0',9600)

firebase = firebase.FirebaseApplication('https://raspi-ph.firebaseio.com/', None)


def update_firebase():
    phair = arduino.readline()
    if data is not None:
        time.sleep(1)
        pieces = data.split("sensor= ")
        ph = pieces
        print ph
    else:
        print('Failed to get data. Try Again!')
        time.sleep(10)

    data = {"Sensor pH": phair}
    firebase.post('/sensor/ph', data)


while True:
    update_firebase()

    time.sleep(5)
```

and here's source code on Arduino

```
const int analogInPin = A0; 
int sensorValue = 0; 
unsigned long int avgValue; 
float b;
int buf[10],temp;
void setup() {
 Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
 for(int i=0;i<10;i++) 
 { 
  buf[i]=analogRead(analogInPin);
  delay(10);
 }
 for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
 {
  for(int j=i+1;j<10;j++)
  {
   if(buf[i]>buf[j])
   {
    temp=buf[i];
    buf[i]=buf[j];
    buf[j]=temp;
   }
  }
 }
 avgValue=0;
 for(int i=2;i<8;i++)
 avgValue+=buf[i];
 float pHVol=(float)avgValue*5.0/1024/6;
 float phValue = -5.70 * pHVol + 21.34;
 Serial.print("sensor = ");
 Serial.println(phValue);

 delay(20);
}
```

last, the error message on raspi

```
['seor= 0.52\r\n']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ard.py", line 27, in <module>
    update_firebase()
  File "ard.py", line 11, in update_firebase
    phair = arduino.readline()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 490, in read
    'device reports readiness to read but returned no data '
serial.serialutil.SerialException: device reports readiness to read but returned no data (device disconnected or multiple access on port?)
```

the looping only run once

Comment: Can you put the *exact* error message in your question?

Comment: The problem is not in PH. The problem is in communication over `UART`. Please, write program on rasperry that ONLY reads data from `UART` and prints. On arduino: write program that ONLY prints "hello from arduino\n".

Comment: I just wanna know how are the two communicating with each other are they using a USB connection or are they running on the same pi?

Comment: using USB connection

Comment: @larsk i put the error message on the question. help me please :((

Comment: Have a look at [Serial Receiving from Arduino to Raspberry Pi with PySerial stops after a while](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20107700). Also please consider giving your question a title that makes it likely to be searched by someone else. May be something like _Python SerialException: Device reports readiness to read but returned no data (device disconnected?)_ (and btw. there is already a [question with that title](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28343941). So, may be this one is interesting for you, too.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Serial Receiving from Arduino to Raspberry Pi with PySerial stops after a while](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20107700/serial-receiving-from-arduino-to-raspberry-pi-with-pyserial-stops-after-a-while)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/pyserial/pyserial/blob/master/serial/serialposix.py#L494), this exception is based on the assumption that ready for reading plus empty data implies a disconnected device.

The way to avoid this behaviour is to specify a `timeout` when creating a `Serial` instance.